# How do I update users specified in file in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

part of my job is to update the status of users like if an account is blocked or when it expires. Normally I just get one user at the time to update, so I use query

`update Users set failedLogin=0,blocked=0,expires="2142-10-17" where login = "user1";`

Now I got nearly a hundred users to update so instead of updating each of them manually, I would like to automate it. How can I read user logins from a file and update them with a query like the one above?

Comment: Try to import the file as an temp table and join it based on user_id then update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use where IN condition like this

```
update Users set failedLogin=0,blocked=0,expires="2142-10-17" where login IN ("user1","user2","user3","user4") ;
```

Comment: I guess that worked. 3 mins in Excel to properly format users and I just copy pasted that into mysql and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds great :)